# jquery radio buttons :checked and $(this).parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

The radio button is checked by default when the page loads. I want the label that wraps around this radio button to have a CSS class added to it.

What's wrong with my code?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3ar43086/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {       
    $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked'); }      
});

<label for="myRadio"><input type="radio" id="myRadio" value="Example Radio Button" name="amount" checked>Example Radio Button</label>

.checked { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: To clarify: the radio button is checked by default when the page loads. I want the label that contains the radio button to have a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this)` in your code refers to `document` instead of the `input`.

This fixes it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')) {            
    $('input[type=radio]').parent('label').addClass('checked'); 
  }
});
```

You could also do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]:checked').parent('label').addClass('checked'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the following line refers to `window`

```
$(this).parent('label').addClass('checked');
```

You should do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myInput = $('input[type=radio]');
    if (myInput.is(':checked')) {       
    myInput.parent('label').addClass('checked'); }      
});
```

Or, if you want to treat all the `input` on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {       
            $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked');
        }      
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, right -- of course. I don't think your first solution works quite as well because if there are multiple radio buttons, all the elements get highlighted. http://jsfiddle.net/3ar43086/6/